# React native TextInput - Trigger/Detect when @ is entered anywhere in textinput OR Get latest character inserted

Tags: react-native

The question is pretty clear.

I want to detect when `@` is entered in the text.
But it should get detected if `@` is entered anywhere in textinput - at end, at start or in middle.

Suppose current text is `This is a text line`.

Now user can add `@` anywhere as below - `@` is the newest/latest character entered.

`@This is a text line`

`This is @a text line`

`This is a text line@`

Any hints, react native experts ?

Basically, I want to detect the newest/latest character entered and not the entire text as we get in `onChangeText` props.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about using String prototype method includes? https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

```
const hasAtSymbol = currentText.includes("@");
```

Comment: It does not work on every trigger. Maybe my question was missing that. Like on whatsapp, at every @ it opens users mention-suggestions list even if already @ is present in text. I found the solution , will post it soon, anyways thanks

Answer (score 1):

use javascript includes method to detect @ any where in text

```
  var str = "@This is a text line";
  var n = str.includes("@");
```

this will return a boolean true or false

Answer (score 0):

Have a try by removing all other characters except the last by the following code.

```
onChangeText(enteredText => {
        let lastCharacter = enteredText.substr(enteredText.length - 1)
        if (lastCharacter === "@") {
            // do something...
        } else {
            // do something else...
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question's demand `anywhere`. Unmentioned requirement was everytime `@` is entered. Found the solution, will post it soon

Answer (score 0):

Solution -

1. In `onSelectionChange`, set the local state as selection object.
2. In `onChangeText`, if length of old value is less than length of new value, then there is new character insertion. The current selection state value will be old position of cursor i.e. one behind the new character. To get this character, use `oldstring.substr(state.selection.start+1)`
3. Then apply check for this character is `@` or not. In this way everytime `@` is entered, then you can detect it.

*This method can be used to get latest character inserted.*